# Mensaje de error: La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor!

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Quiero comparar los registros que guardo en ambas variables los cuales son los días de la semana para asignar faltas de acuerdo al horario de cada prestatario automáticamente en un sistema de registro de entrada y salida.
Y tengo un problema con este código:

```
select Id_Prestatario,Dia from Cg_PrestHora ph join Cg_Horarios h on ph.Id_Horario=h.Id_Horario where 
Id_Prestatario not in (SELECT p.Id_prestatario FROM Cg_Prestatario p join CG_TIEMPO ti on p.Id_prestatario=ti.Id_prestatario 
       join cg_terminacion t on p.Id_prestatario=t.Id_prestatario where vigente='D')

declare @Dia varchar(10) =  (select Dia from Cg_Horarios)
declare @Dia1 varchar(10) =(SELECT DATENAME(dw,(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3)AS Dia)))


if(@Dia = @Dia1)

SELECT p.id_prestatario,fecha=(@Dia1),activa='S',justificante=''
FROM Cg_Prestatario p join cg_terminacion t on p.id_prestatario=t.id_prestatario 
where VIGENTE='D'  and p.id_prestatario  not in 
(

SELECT p.id_prestatario FROM Cg_Prestatario p join CG_TIEMPO t on p.id_prestatario=t.id_prestatario
join cg_terminacion tE on p.id_prestatario=tE.id_prestatario
WHERE FECHA  IN (@Dia1) AND VIGENTE='D'
)
```

Que muestra este mensaje de error:

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

Comment: Si `Cg_Horarios` contiene mas de un registro, obviamente esta sentencia no tiene sentido: `declare @Dia varchar(10) =  (select Dia from Cg_Horarios)`. ¿Cual `Dia` deberías asignar a esa variable si la tabla tiene varios registros con `Dia`? Vas a tener que explicar mas en cuanto a la lógica de tu código.

Comment: Busco comparar todos los registros de esa columna con los registros que le asigno a @Dia1 que también contiene mas de un registro. :(

Comment: Disculpa, pero para mi, no es claro lo que tratas de hacer. Y sin entender, podríamos sugerirte algo que elimine el error, pero que no produciría el resultado esperado. A ver si otros entienden. Pero yo creo que necesitas agregar una explicación mucho mas completa en tu pregunta (usa el enlace `editar` debajo de la pregunta).

Comment: Hola sstan gracias por contestar, espero explicarme mejor, he estado investigando y lo que quiero es asignar varios registros a una variable he visto que puedo hacerlo con datos tipo table pero no me resulta y hay otras opciones como vistas o procedures pero apenas voy a checar si me funcionan.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Dia varchar(10) =  (select Dia from Cg_Horarios)
```

Aquí en la subconsulta debes de colocar una condición where para que te traiga un dato en especifico porque trae mas de un registro

Comment: Hola Ing. Jose esa es la idea, asignar varios registro a las variable para después compararlos

Comment: pero en una subconsulta nada mas debes almacenar un valor de lo contrario te va indicar el error que te esta indicando, así que debes ser mas especifico con lo que quieres

Comment: Específica! entonces como puedo hacer que una variable me guarde esos registros con esa subconsulta?

Comment: @Itzel Serrano Oropeza te recomiendo que edites la pregunta, especificando lo que quieres que haga el código para entenderlo y luego colocas el código, porque si no no te vamos a entender porque en una variable solo puedes almacenar un registro

Comment: Te indico nuevamente en la variable día te esta indicando mas de un valor, si quieres comparar los registros que hay en día tienes que hacer un bucle porque así como lo estas haciendo no podrás

Comment: ok y como puedo crear el bucle? estoy intentando hacerlo al cambiar el tipo de datos de las variables por tipo table pero no funciona.

Comment: si puedes, un while e ir recorriendo los valores que te traiga e ir evaluandolos